# PHP regular expression doesn't work

Tags: php, regex, email

I got a probleme with one of my regular expression; if you can help me :

```
<?php 
$ptn = "/[\S]*[A-Za-z0-9_-]*.*[A-Za-z0-9_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9_-]*.*[A-Za-z0-9_-]*[\S]*/";
$str = "Contact name: Wahyu van Schneppanginen Email: perm@perotozair.com ";
preg_match($ptn, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Howver the result is :

```
   Array
   (
       [0] =>                           Email:                    perm@perotozair.com  
   )
```

But I want :

```
   Array
   (
       [0] => perm@perotozair.com  
   )
```

If any of you can help me I'd be glad

Thanks !

Comment: You didn't tell what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :-

```
 <?php 
    $ptn = "/[A-Za-z0-9_-].[A-Za-z0-9_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9_-]*.*[A-Za-z0-9_-]*/";
    $str = "Contact name: Wahyu van Schneppanginen Email: perm@perotozair.com ";
    preg_match($ptn, $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
    ?>
```

Comment: *"Try this:"* is a [subpar answer decoration](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help10). Instead please add a slim explanation of *what* your code does, *why* you'd recommend it, or *how* you came to the conclusion.

Comment: According to @mario this wont work if the string has 2 email ids. But works perfect if it has one.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
<?php 
$ptn = '/[\w\d-]+(?:\.[\w\d-]+)*@[\w\d-]+(?:\.[\w\d-]+)+/';
$str = "Contact name: Wahyu van Schneppanginen Email: perm@perotozair.com bla bla bla xxx@yyy.com";
preg_match_all($ptn, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Your problem were the word boundarys you were using: `[\S]*`. You should instead use `\b` for that. I also simplified and improved your regex to rigth-match e-mail addresses by grouping some parts. Note the use of `preg_match_all()` to match all the occurrences of an e-mail address in the string.

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => perm@perotozair.com
            [1] => xxx@yyy.com
        )

)
```

Comment: When i run this it gives me an empty array.

Comment: I copy pasted the whole code and tried to run here  http://writecodeonline.com/php/   . It still outputs a blank array

Comment: I am sorry. This does work in my localhost but if the string has 2 email ids it wont.

Comment: @AbhishekSaha I was using `preg_match()` instead of `preg_match_all()`. My fault!

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you use explode ?

```
$str = "Contact name: Wahyu van Schneppanginen Email: perm@perotozair.com ";
$strArr = explode("Email: ",$str);
if(isset($strArr[1]))
    $email = $strArr[1]; //output: perm@perotozair.com
else
    echo "Email not found";
```

Comment: *Why* `explode`? Please elaborate why the fiddly approach is what OP should use. Are you sure he doesn't have extra input data, and Email: really only occurs once?

Comment: He didnt specify his complete requirement and other variations he can have. This is one of the solution which will work but might not work for all variations which he didnt mention. The email is the output which he requires and this solution is still valid for that.